# UIActivityIndicator as long as to implement function

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to use UIActivityIndicator on a function.

I'm implementing some Core Filters, some of which take almost a second to implement. I want that UIActivityIndicator to start and stop according the function.

I looked up online, but it's mostly using a timer. So that would make it hard-wired and not based on how long it actually takes to implement the function.

Can someone tell me a small example how I can do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Declare ActivityIndicator

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicatorView;
```

then,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{ 
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 

  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib. 
  CGRect frame = CGRectMake (120.0, 185.0, 80, 80);

  self.activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

  [self.view addSubview:self.activityIndicatorView];
}
```

using this code you can start and stop the activityIndicator

```
[self.activityIndicatorView startAnimating];  //start
[self.activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];   //stop
```

Answer (score 0):

all UI animation and navigation would be performed once the method execution is over. So if you want such functionality go for timer or dispatch queue.

as follows

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.frame];
    [activity startAnimating];
    //Your methods to be executed
    double delayInSeconds = 0.01;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [activity stopAnimating];
    });
```

in this method execution is kept in a queue after the execution of current method, method written dispatch_time_t will be executed.

Comment: This won't work. If the "methods to be executed" are done on the main thread, the activity view will never start animating. If those methods are done in the background, the call to stop animating will happen long before those methods complete.